# Teamspeak Server autorestart when it´s not working or having issues

Tags: server, scripts, restart, autostart, teamspeak

I have a Teamspeak Server running on my Linux (Ubuntu) Server. So here´s the question:
when the teamspeak did not work right like he didn´t start or the ts server shut down because of an error. i want that the ts server automtaticly restarts by his own so that when the server goes offline in the midnight that it starts up again.

did anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly asking? It's not clear, are you saying you have a service up and running and want to restart if it crashes? Is it started manually by you with a 'teamspeak.starter start' what are you exactly doing?

However assuming you have a systemd .service file you need to add:

```
Restart=always
```

and

```
RestartSec=5
```

+reload the cache

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now you can try killing your teamspeak service and see that it will restart.